# Access a cell in datalist after click button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to Access a cell in data list after click button and Transmission to Variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /><br />        

     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>'  />

        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:C}") %>'></asp:Label><br />

        <asp:Button ID="buyNowBtn" runat="server" Text="buy Now" OnClick="buyNowBtn_Click" />                     
    </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>
```

Below i also have 2 Label control that is going to display the ProductName and Price

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

```
 protected void BuyNowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Button BuyNowButton = (Button)sender;
                DataListItem item = (DataListItem)BuyNowButton.NamingContainer;
                Label NameLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("NameLabel");
                Label ValueLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("ValueLabel");
                ResultsLabel.Text += String.Format("Click: {0} - {1}
", NameLabel.Text, ValueLabel.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code looks neat, but when you'll click any control located inside the DataGrid, the first fired event would be   `protected void DataListName_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)` , Hence it will be precise to put the code inside the event.

And then you can find the items in the same way

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("ImageButton1");
img.(property that you wanna access)
```